# Django querying many to many relations

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 3 models:  group, word, phrase

As you can see word belongs to group and there is a many to many relation between phrases and words:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()


class Word(models.Model):  
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,
    related_name = "words")

class Phrase(models.Model):
    words = models.ManyToManyField(Word, null=True,related_name = "phrases")
    name = models.TextField()
```

And right now I need to find all `phrases`with `name ="xxx"` 
that have at least one  `word` from `group with group id = '177'`

How do I do this?

Comment: But a `Phrase` have no `name`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem right now it has)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Phrase.objects.filter(name="xxx", words__group__id=177)
```

You can filter all phrases  with name "xxx" and one of words' group_id equals 177.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a filter that both filters on the `name` field, and the `words__group_id=177`:

```
Phrase.objects.filter(
    name='xxx',
    words__group_id=177
).distinct()
```

We here thus use a `JOIN` on the `words` and the `phrase_words` table, and then filter such that the `group_id` of the `Word` is `177`.

The `.distinct()` can be important, since if *mutliple* `words` are in the `group` with `id` 177, then that `Phrase` would be repeated *multiple* times.

This works in case `id` is the *primary key* of the `Group`. If you defined another column named `id`, and that column is *not* the primary key (which is quite uncommon), we can use:

```
Phrase.objects.filter(
    name='xxx',
    words__group__id=177
).distinct()
```

Mind that here we use two consecutive underscores (`__`) instead of one (`_`) to look "through" the foreign key. In this case, this will result in an extra `JOIN` at the database level, and therfore can be a bit less efficient.